# Sorting a vector of objects with std::sort()

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

I have the following struct:

```
struct Invariant
{
public:
    Invariant(int d, int dc)
    : Dim(d), DimCoupl(dc) {}
    void addTerm(int coeff, intVec pows)
    {
        Powers.push_back(pows);
        Coefficients.push_back(coeff);
    }

    int Dim, DimCoupl;
    std::vector<long> Coefficients;
    std::vector<intVec> Powers;
};
```

Where `IntVec` is a custom array of ints that's based on the arrays from the Boost library.

I have an stl Vector of these object, and I'd like to sort them by the amount of elements of their Coefficients vectors. So I define:

```
bool compInv(const Invariant &one, const Invariant &two)
{
    return (one.Coefficients.size() < two.Coefficients.size());
}
```

And use `std::sort()` or `std::stable_sort()` to sort the Vector. Checking afterwards, the Vector is sorted, but is seems like the content of `std::vector<intVec>` Powers is changed. Furthermore, `std::sort()` and `std::stable_sort()` seem to alter them in a different way. What could be causing this?

Edit: The definition of the IntVec:

```
typedef blitz::Array<int,1> intVec;
```

Which I use because they are easier to initialize than regular arrays, which is very important since I have to create a lot of these objects that each contain a lot of these vectors.

Comment: If that happens, then your `intVec` class (and its `swap` or assignment operator in particular) is broken. Why are you rolling your own?

Comment: I'd thought that `std::sort` uses `std::swap`. It may be that swapping your `IntVec` is not doing what you think (i.e. that your `IntVec` class is broken).

Comment: I added the definition of intVec. I'll edit in the result of the sort() function if that helps.

Comment: the answer is: **don't use blitz++**. It's no longer updated/debugged; it will never take advantage of/support more recent C++ standards (like the current 2011 standard). It's online documentation is dated March 2006: over 7 years old.

Comment: @RobVerheyen: It's not enough. It's not reproducible. A typedef is not useful at all. Either provide the definition of `blitz:Array<>` or, far better, abstract it away.

Comment: C++11 pretty much invalidates your reason to use blitz++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a SSCCE it's hard to tell what is wrong with your code, but it looks like you're caught by using a class from an outdated library (blitz++), which seemed to have ceased further development/updating/debugging several years ago.

Since `blitz::Array<int,1>` is a dynamically allocated 1D array of integers, there is no advantage over carefully using `std::vector<int>` instead, when you get the full support (correct swap) and C++11 features (move semantics). So, the first thing to try is

```
typedef std::vector<int> intVec;
```

and see if the symptoms persist. If this involves too many changes to your code, try this first with a SSCCE (which initially must show the same symptoms as your code).

Comment: I'm going to try this, but it will take me a while. It requires me to change a very large part of my code, so I won't be able to see if it works immediately. Thanks!

Comment: @RobVerheyen shouldn't require you to make many changes: it's a simple `typedef`. What else do you need to change? And for testing this issue, you only need to compile a few files. Also, you can generate a SSCCE and make the change there, before committing to change all your code.

Comment: You are probably right, but this is a good opportunity to get rid of using the Blitz library altogether. I use it in a lot of other places in the code, and more specifically the intVecs in the objects are created through methods that use other intVecs/other Blitz types, so I might as well replace all of them.